# Synchronize to Subversion after importing new sources in my Eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, date, ant

On the project I am working on, we receive the sources from an external contractor, and we need to version those sources in our SVN repository. For that, I have a simple Ant task :

```
<sync todir="${basedir}"
      includeemptydirs="false"
      verbose="true">
    <fileset dir="${new.src.dir}"
             defaultexcludes="false">
        <exclude name="**/.svn" />
        <exclude name="**/.svn/**" />
    </fileset>
    <preserveintarget>
        <include name="**/.svn" />
        <include name="**/.svn/**" />
        <include name="build-local.properties" />
        <include name="build-local.xml" />
    </preserveintarget>
</sync>
```

This works almost correctly. I still have the problem that some files have only their dates that have changed. The sync target copies them and then when I try to sync my Eclipse project with SVN I have alot of changes that are actually not significant. I would like to ignore those changes where only the file modification date has changed. The problem is not the granularity, as some times the dates are many days appart. This could be solved either by having Ant not update the file dates, or by having the Eclipse SVN plugin ignoring file dates when synchronising my project with SVN.

Is it possible ?

I use :

- Ant 1.7.1
- Eclipse 3.6
- Eclipse Subversive plugin

Thanks for your help !

**Edit :** It seems that the problem doesnt come from file dates, but from Unix / Dos newline convertion.